# Alert user on triggered update to mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, database, alert

Does anyone know of a simple PHP code that can be added to a web page which will inform the user that new data from a mysql database has been added to their user area?

Comment: This needs more than some PHP code - at least some JS to actually request the PHP!

Comment: Dan, this question really needs a bit more information. It's not entirely clear what you're asking, and as such, your question may be in danger of getting closed. Please provide as much detail necessary to better understand your problem.

Answer (score 4):

For this you need to make an ajax call to the php page which will check from database if there are new records while checking with previous one it will return new record or else return 0.

check `$.ajax` in `jQuery`, `setTimeout` `js` method and you need `.php` page for dynamic data manipulation!